# addClass to a specific element

Tags: jquery, pagination, element, addclass

My question comes because I don't know almost anything about jQuery and I'm using a script for pagination in Bootstrap (http://www.bootply.com/xu9mT0pPA6) and I saw that for what I understand that in this line `$('.pager .page_link:first').addClass('active');` the class active is added to an anchor that is before, and it has to be added to the li element.

I have tried putting `$('.pager **li** .page_link:first').addClass('active');` but it doesn't work.

Thanks a lot

EDIT: The code:

```
var listElement = $('#pageStuff');
var perPage = 2; 
var numItems = listElement.children().size();
var numPages = Math.ceil(numItems/perPage);

$('.pager').data("curr",0);

var curr = 0;
**while(numPages > curr){
  $('<li><a href="#" class="page_link">'+(curr+1)+'</a></li>').appendTo('.pager');
  curr++;
}

$('.pager .page_link:first').addClass('active');**

listElement.children().css('display', 'none');
listElement.children().slice(0, perPage).css('display', 'block');

$('.pager li a').click(function(){
  var clickedPage = $(this).html().valueOf() - 1;
  goTo(clickedPage,perPage);
});

function previous(){
  var goToPage = parseInt($('.pager').data("curr")) - 1;
  if($('.active').prev('.page_link').length==true){
    goTo(goToPage);
  }
}

function next(){
  goToPage = parseInt($('.pager').data("curr")) + 1;
  if($('.active_page').next('.page_link').length==true){
    goTo(goToPage);
  }
}

function goTo(page){
  var startAt = page * perPage,
    endOn = startAt + perPage;

  listElement.children().css('display','none').slice(startAt, endOn).css('display','block');
  $('.pager').attr("curr",page);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This little snippet adds `active` class to the clicked `<li>`:

```
//when the anchor tag is clicked
$('a.page_link').click(function(){
  $('li').each(function(){
    //remove all li with class active (this is to remove the previous active)
    $(this).removeClass('active');
  });
  //add active to the parent of the clicked a tag
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/EBiIQxUm2l)**

Answer (score 1):

Since `li` is the parent of `.page_link`, you can either use `.closest("li")`

```
$('.pager .page_link:first').closest("li").addClass('active');
```

or `.parent()`

```
$('.pager .page_link:first').parent().addClass('active');
```

**Edit**

```
$('.pager li a').click(function(){
  var clickedPage = $(this).html().valueOf() - 1;

  $(".active").removeClass("active");
  $(this).closest("li").addClass("active"); 
  goTo(clickedPage,perPage);
});
```

Comment: The second one doesn't work..but the first one does.
But now the first li element is always active, if I click on the second element this doesn't change to active, I don't know why
Thanks anyway!